# How to keep checking a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to keep checking a MySQL database and then update text? I'm using this to get the number of rows and then it's echo-ed:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM socialacc WHERE transid='$transID' AND access='$access'");
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $i = $i + 1;
}
echo $i;
```

I want this code to be repeated so that if there's ever another row that matches, the text would be updated without the page being reloaded. Would I use Javascript to repeat the check? Any idea's how I would go about it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, you'd typically use AJAX for that.

Comment: To get the number of rows retrieved use mysql_num_rows() instead of that while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices here: [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) or [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Server push is probably simpler to program at the client side but quite complicated to write the server side in a way that won't eat some system resource or other on your server. AJAX more complicated at the client side, but simpler and easier to implement overall.

I would recommend the AJAX route for this job.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at AJAX :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can let the database count for you:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM socialacc WHERE transid='$transID' AND access='$access'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $result[0];
```

Then, you'll probably want to repeat this query every so often through an AJAX call, but not so often that it'll kill your database.

Comment: Indeed, let the databse count, performance will be greatly improved!